# How do I find attributes starting with a specific value using HTML Agility Pack?

Tags: html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to find any attributes within an HTML document that start with a particular value. I seem to have a valid XPath query for this but it returns nothing when using HTML Agility Pack.

I'm aware I could be using Linq but I'm attempting to reuse existing functionality and leverage an XPath query.

Example HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Loren ipsum</p>
<a href="http://www.myurl.com" onclick="myFunction()"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

XPath query

```
//*/@*[starts-with(name(), 'on')]
```

Is this possible using HTML Agility Pack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using HtmlAgilityPack (HAP) and XPath function `name()` didn't work for me, but replacing `name()` with `local-name()` did the trick :

```
//*/@*[starts-with(local-name(), 'on')]
```

However, both `SelectSingleNode()` and `SelectNodes()` only able to return `HtmlNode`(s). When the XPath expression selects an attribute instead of node, the attribute's owner node would be returned. So in the end you still need to get the attribute through some options besides XPath, for example :

```cs
HtmlDocument doc;
......
var link = doc.DocumentNode
              .SelectSingleNode("//*/@*[starts-with(local-name(), 'on')]");
var onclick = link.Attributes
                  .First(o => o.Name.StartsWith("on"));
```

Comment: The difference between `name()` and `local-name()` seems really odd  - if an attribute is in no namespace (as is the case with the input document above), both functions should return exactly the same. You should consider reporting a bug if that's not the case.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of `local-name()` but I agree with Mathias that this seems a little strange.

Comment: I've raised an issue in the Html Agility Pack project and will update if anything happens with it https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/35920

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression is correct. Taking as input the document snippet you have shown, the result is

```
onclick="myFunction()"
```

So, yes this is definitely possible and XPath is not at fault here, the problem lies somewhere else. Perhaps you could show the code that invokes the expression? Do you use `SelectSingleNode()`?

Comment: As Mathias  says, you might want to lookinto your c# code rather than the Xpath e.g var someValue = documenturl.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("XPATH")[0].Attributes["onclick"].Value;

Comment: The method being used is `SelectNodes()`, testing with `SelectSingleNode()` still brings back no results.

Comment: @Helmer As described in the question I wish to do this using a single XPath query ideally. I can achieve the results in another manner, I'm just trying not to.